# Connecting Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 from Windows via Network Cable using ssh(putty)

Tags: network-manager, windows-10

I wanted to connect to my Ubuntu desktop(18.04) from my windows 10 laptop via network cable and be able to access the Ubuntu system using putty.

Is it possible to do so ? and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible using any ethernet cable. Now a days the network cards are smart enough to do crossover themselves hence we don't need a specific crossover ethernet cable to do this direct connection.

Reference [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251057/can-i-connect-a-ubuntu-linux-laptop-to-a-windows-10-laptop-via-ethernet-cable).